# Nested query | Elastic Search

Tags: curl, elasticsearch, nested

I have tried to look for an answer to this everywhere but I have not been successful on finding it. I have a simple index for users in which I use the following query to fetch some results:

```
1. curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/users/_search?pretty' -d'
{
"explain": true, 
"query": {
 "match": {
  "skills": {
   "query": "im looking for some business counseling",
   "operator": "or",
   "fuzziness": "auto",
   "analyzer": "search_analyzer"
   }
  }
 },
"sort": [
 {"_score": "desc"}
 ],
}'
```

This query successfully gives me the results desired...Now the part where I have been lost is on how to use the following query (#2) to query the documents just fetched from the query above (#1). (btw I have tried using all the types of compound queries found in the documentation from elastic.co but the problem is that they only query one set of documents based on different criteria? or am I wrong?):

```
 2. "query": {
 "match": {
  "search": {
   "query": "now I want to query the documents just fetched with this text",
   "operator": "or",
   "fuzziness": "auto",
   "analyzer": "search_analyzer"
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: And why do you want these things to run in that particular order?

Comment: The reason why I want to do it in this order is because I want to do some cross-matching

Answer (score 0):

So after digging through the documentation again I ended up finding an answer with the compound bool query...It looks like this:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/users/_search?pretty' -d'
{
 "explain": true,
  "query": {
   "bool": {
    "should": [
    { "match": { "skills":  "Im looking for somebody with business skills"}},
    { "bool":  {
      "should": [
        { "match": { "search": "someone is looking for my skills which are cooking,caking, and entertaining" }}
        ]
      }}
    ]
  }
},
"sort": [
 {"_score": "desc"}
 ]
}'
```

With a mapping of the index looking like so:

```
{
"settings": {
    "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
            "search_analyzer": {
            "type": "custom",
                "tokenizer": "punctuation",
                "filter":  ["lowercase","apostrophe","asciifolding","stop_analyzer","kstem"]
            }
        },
        "tokenizer": {
            "punctuation": {
                "type": "pattern",
                "pattern": "[ .,!?+&@=-]"
            }
        },
        "filter": {
            "stop_analyzer": {
                "type": "stop"
            }
        }
    }
},
 "mappings": {
        "users": {
            "properties": {
                "skills": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "norms": { "enabled": false },
                    "analyzer": "search_analyzer"
                },
                "search": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "norms": { "enabled": false },
                    "analyzer": "search_analyzer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```